# Can't touch UITextField on UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uitextfield, textfield, scrollview

I know this has been talked about a lot.  I think I've gone thru every question on this site, and still have not been able to get this working.

I'm new to developing but I have a good sense of what's going on with all of my code. I definitely don't have a lot of experience though, this is my first iPhone app.

I'm making a data entry field that is comprised of multiple UITextFields within a UIScrollView.  I'll avoid explaining the other details for now, as it seems its a very basic problem.  Without a scrollview, the textfields work perfectly.  I can touch the textfield and the keyboard or picker view show up appropriately.  When I add the textfields to a scrollview, the scrollview works, but then the text fields don't receive my touches.
Here's the key: When 'User Interaction' is ENABLED, the scrollview works but the textfield touches are NOT registered.  When 'User Interaction' is DISABLED, the scrollview doesn't work, but the textfield touches ARE registered and the keyboard/picker pops up.

From the other posts I have seen people creating subclasses and overriding the touches in a  separate implementation.  I've seen people using custom content views (subviews?), I've seen some solutions that are now obsolete since the APIs have changed in newer versions of the SDK, and I am just completely stuck.

I will leave out my code for now, because maybe there is a solution that someone has without requiring my code.  If someone needs to see my code, I will put it up.  My app is being written in the 3.1.3 SDK.

If anyone has ANY information that could help, it would be so greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Here is what worked for me in `Xcode 4.3.3`.

In the storyboard, select your `scrollview`. Select `Attribute Inspector` on the right side. Uncheck `Delays Content Touches`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this should be the correct answer, i did this and finally worked!!! really really thanks a lot!

Comment: This does not seem to work for xCode 14.1, at least not when doing it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're using IB to do a lot of your UI layout. If you take a programmatic approach you could set-up the following view hierarchy which should work.

Your view controller object managing your scroll view and your text fields should have a `UIScrollView` object and a `UIView` object (in addition to any `UITextField` objects you need). In the loadView method of the view controller class, allocate and initalize the `UIView` object and add your text fields to it as subviews. At the end of the method, allocate and initalize the `UIScrollView` object then add the `UIView` to the `UIScrollView` as a subview.

As an example, if your `UIScrollView` object were called scrollView and your `UIView` object called mainView the following lines at the end of the view controller's loadView method would properly set up the scroll view with the main view with the text fields on it:

```
scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds] ];
scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
scrollView.contentSize = mainView.frame.size;
[scrollView addSubview: mainView];
self.view = scrollView;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to enable / disable user interaction for both the scroll view and text fields as necessary.

If possible you might best using different touch mechanisms for each process (scrolling and textfield input).

Maybe you can check the time differential between touch start and end such that you can detect the difference between a drag (scroll) and a tap (text input).

Having said that if you propagate the touches up from the textfields to the scrollview you should be fine. One thing I use is:

```
[myObject addTarget:self action:@selector(itemTouchedUpInside:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

which passes the object touched so you can identify it and act accordingly.